# Angular-nvD3(krispo) single line chart with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, linechart, angular-nvd3

I'm trying to render different charts from an array named `$scope.dataset` with ng-repeat but it is not happening.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in dataset">
   <nvd3 options="options" data="data" class="with-3d-shadow with-transitions"></nvd3>
</div>
```

But I get this in firefox console-

`Error: a.map is not a function`

So I tried to put the same code in their plunkr - [linechart-nvd3](http://plnkr.co/edit/lBKFld?p=preview), and that did not work either. However the graph renders when I use the whole array i.e. `$scope.dataset` rather than using `ng-repeat`. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your sinAndCos() method:

```
//Line chart data should be sent as an array of series objects.
            return [
                [{
                    values: sin,      //values - represents the array of {x,y} data points
                    key: 'Sine Wave', //key  - the name of the series.
                    color: '#ff7f0e',  //color - optional: choose your own line color.
                    strokeWidth: 2,
                    classed: 'dashed'
                }],
                [{
                    values: cos,
                    key: 'Cosine Wave',
                    color: '#2ca02c'
                }],
                [{
                    values: sin2,
                    key: 'Another sine wave',
                    color: '#7777ff',
                    area: true      //area - set to true if you want this line to turn into a filled area chart.
                }]
            ];
```

So put the same code in your plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/lBKFld?p=preview.

Note: Angular-nvD3 chart you have to send array of object. Here I send each element as a array of object. Now if you use ng-repeat then it will work perfectly.